# How to create a Shutdown Script for Server 2016

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2016, batch, shutdown

I have a Windows 2016 server running an Oracle database that needs to be manually shutdown before the server shuts down.

I enabled the local GPO (Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Scripts > Shutdown) and attached the shutdown script to it (below), but now it takes an extra ten minutes to shutdown (this script should only take 30sec to execute). This is a problem because the UPS will generally shut the server off before its finished shutting down.

I read somewhere that the default time Windows gives for shutdown scripts is ten min before it ends the process, so I'm worried that its not even executing properly, and there is no way to tell if it is.

```
Stop-oracle.cmd
*********************
@ECHO OFF

net session >nul 2>&1
if %errorLevel% == 0 (
   goto runControlScript
) else (
   echo Administrative permission required!
   goto exit
)
:runControlScript

:: variables
SET IFS_HOME=E:/H381
SET INSTANCE=H381-IFS

SET JAVA_HOME=%IFS_HOME%/mw_home/java
SET TOOL_CLASSES=%IFS_HOME%/repository/installer/templates/j2ee/as/mws-svr-ctrl.jar
SET JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -DIFS_HOME=%IFS_HOME% -DINSTANCE=%INSTANCE%
SET CLASSPATH=%IFS_HOME%/mw_home/mws/wlserver/modules/features/wlst.wls.classpath.jar;%TOOL_CLASSES%

:: check if we should pause after running the app
%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java -cp .;%CLASSPATH% %JAVA_OPTIONS% com.ifsworld.mws.utils.ShouldPause "/cmdline=%cmdcmdline%" "/cmd=%~0" %*
:: non 0 errorlevel indicates that we should pause the script
set _SHOULD_PAUSE_=%ERRORLEVEL%

:: run the app
%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java -cp .;%CLASSPATH% %JAVA_OPTIONS% com.ifsworld.mws.ServerController /user=ifs /password=Im9ract1ca1 /action=STOP /target=all %*

IF %_SHOULD_PAUSE_% NEQ 0 (
  PAUSE
)

ECHO "Stopping the Database"

oradim -SHUTDOWN -SID H381CDB -SHUTTYPE srvc,inst -SHUTMODE immediate

IF %errorLevel% == 0  (
 ECHO IFS and Database shutdown Command Completed
 PAUSE
)

IF %_SHOULD_PAUSE_% NEQ 0 (
  PAUSE
)

:exit
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: Hard to imagine a worse command to put in a script that should run unattended than a pause command. You need to create a log file for all output of the script to see how far it progresses.

Comment: Good Catch! I just removed all the pause commands and added >> log.txt to every line, but when I shutdown the server it still took ten min on stopping group policies, and didn't even create the log file

Comment: Logoff/Shutdown Scripts are executed as 'local system', not within a users' context (thus having no local variables or network access rights). Does your script work when started as such (try with psexec)? If not, triple check you file permissions.